# Address-decoder and its address-range

Tags: microcontroller

I have a model of an address-decoder and problems understanding it. 
The circuit shows 4 16 x 4 memory-chips that are connected to a 64 x 4 bit memory.
Could someone explain to me what address each block occupies?

[image]

Comment: Take a close look at the nodes on the AND gates.  The black dots are inversions. The gates are connected to 2 address lines.  Do you see what's going on there?

Comment: To be frank, not really. I managed to do the logic-table that shows me all possible values for each block, but still, I can't figure it out

Comment: Look at A4 and A5, the AND gates, and the EN.  EN means "Enable."  When EN is low, the chip is active.

Comment: which one of the AND gates has a low output when A4 and A5 are both high?

Answer (score 2):

All chips have active low chip-enable and a glue logic in the form of a gate, driven by A5 and A6 bits of the 6 bit address bus [A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0] . So A5 and A6 bits decide which chip will represent what address range.

1. MA is enabled only when A5 = 1 and A4 = 1. All other chips are disabled and hence only MA drives the data bus. So it will address the memory from  **11**0000 to **11**1111.
2. Similarly MB is enabled only when A5 = 1 and A4 = 0. So it will address the memory from  **10**0000 to **10**1111.
3. MC: **01**0000  to **01**1111.
4. MD: **00**0000 to **00**1111.

Answer (score 1):

These are the four gate types used for the enable control:

[image]